# Javascript run after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have a collapsible div in my project that once the user clicks on it and it expands, I need it the computer to scroll down so the user knows the text is there.  The expansion of the div works but since it tries to expand automatically (before the div expands) and because this is the bottom of the page (prior to the Div opening) it will not scroll.  So what I want to do is put in a 3 second delay in to my Javascript so it will not try to do that until the Div is open.  I cannot get it to work.  This is the code I currently have:

```
<script language="Javascript">


     function scrollRefund() {
         var divPosition = $('#refund').offset();

         setTimeout(function(){
             $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divPosition.top }, "slow");
         }, 1);
     }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refund" onclick="javascript: scrollRefund();">Refund Policy</button>

<div id="refund" class="collapse">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument for setTimeout is in milliseconds.  Try 3000 instead of 1.

```
<script language="Javascript">


     function scrollRefund() {
         var divPosition = $('#refund').offset();

         setTimeout(function(){
             $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divPosition.top }, "slow");
         }, 3000);
     }
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refund" onclick="javascript: scrollRefund();">Refund Policy</button>

<div id="refund" class="collapse">
```

Comment: Thank you - that works but not all the time and when it does it will scroll down and then scroll back up.  Do you have any idea why this would be the behavior?

Comment: It's possible that it's trying to find the offset.top before its at the final resting spot. Move the line with var divPosition inside the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```js
setTimeout(function(){
             $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: divPosition.top }, "slow");
         }, 3000);
```